# Pass a function into the __post_init__ method of dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass that I would like to set a value when initializing the class.

```
@dataclass
class classA:

    __data: DataFrame
    __Limit: float
    __totalLimit: float = field(init=False)


    def __post_init__(self):

        # This Does not work
        __setTotalLimit()

        # This works when i put the logic in.
        # self.__totalLimit = self.__data['Amount'].sum()

    def __setTotalLimit(self):
        self.__totalLimit = self.__data['Amount'].sum()
```

This is the error I am getting: 
NameError: name '_classA__setTotalLimit' is not defined

Basically as soon as data is passed in, i need to sum up a column and set that as a variable because it will be used throughout the script.

Comment: Why are you mangling all the names in your dataclass?

Comment: You aren't trying to *pass a function* into `__post_init__`, you are trying to *call a method from another method*. This has **nothing** to do with data classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to refer to the method using `self`:

```
def __post_init__(self):
    self.__setTotalLimit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Use like this:

```
def __post_init__(self):
    self.__setTotalLimit()
```

If the field does not actually need data from the instance, then don't use `__post_init__` at all, but use the [`default_factory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#default-factory-functions) option when adding the field itself, providing a zero-arg callable.

Note that it is strange to `__name_mangle` every dataclass field like that. You should probably just use normal attributes.